Outer measure, $|A| = \lim_{t\to\infty} |A \cap (-t,t)|$ for all $A\subset \mathbb{R}$.
I have already proved this result:
If $A\subset R$ and $t>0$, then $|A| = |A\cap (-t,t)| + |A\cap(\mathbb{R}\setminus(-t,t))|$
I would like to prove that $|A| = \lim_{t\to\infty} |A \cap (-t,t)|$ for all $A\subset \mathbb{R}$.
All I have is basic facts about the outer measure. I saw responses to this question that invoked monotone convergence theorem, and other topics that aren't found until later in the book (Axler - Measure, Integration, and Real Analysis).
I believe that I have proved this for $|A|<\infty$. However, I am stuck on proving it for $|A|=\infty$.
My proof:
Let $|A|<\infty$ and $\epsilon >0$. Let $I_1$, $I_2$, ... be a sequence of open intervals covering $A$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k) < |A| + \epsilon < \infty$ where $l(I)$ is the length of an open interval. Then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty l(I_k)$ converges. There exists an $N$ such that the tail of this sum is arbitrarily small, ie $\sum_{k=N}^\infty l(I_k) < \epsilon$. Now, label the left and right end points of $I_k$ as $a_k$ and $b_k$, respectively. Define:
$M = max\{|a_k|,|b_k|: 1\leq k\leq N\}$. Let $t>M$.
Notice that for $k=1, ... , N$, $I_k \subset (-t,t)$ by the way we have defined $t$ larger than the max of the absolute value of the endpoints of these N intervals.
Clearly, $I_1, I_2,$... covers $A\setminus (-t,t)$, since $I_1$, .... covers $A$. However, if $x\in A\setminus (-t,t)$, then $x\notin I_1, ... , I_N$. So $I_{N+1} , I_{N+2}$ , .... cover $A\setminus(-t,t)$.
$$|A\setminus (-t,t)| ≤ \sum_{N+1}^\infty l(I_k) < \epsilon$$
from how we defined N.
We have shown that there exists $M$ such that $t>M$, $|A\setminus(-t,t)| < \epsilon$. So $\lim t\to \infty |A\setminus (-t,t)| = 0$.
From our previous result, $A = \lim_{t\to \infty} |A\cap (-t,t)| + \lim_{t\to \infty} |A\setminus (-t,t)| = \lim_{t\to \infty} |A\cap (-t,t)|$, proving the result.
Can someone help direct me to an approach that works for the $|A|=\infty$ case? What I want is to show that for all $M>0$, $\exists N$ such that $t>N$ implies $|A\cap(-t,t)|>M$.
Thank you!
